# How to make string format exception in py

Tags: python, string, format

OK, 1st of all see my code

```
msg = '{username} joined {servername} {extra}'

value = {'username': '@Random', 'servername': 'AnyName'}
msg = msg.format(**value)
print(msg)
```

This code throwing this error

```
msg = msg.format(**value)
KeyError: 'extra'
```

My code work perfectly fine if I don't put {extra} in `msg` but it necessary to add sometime like that and it should not change.
I know I can do this by adding `{{extra}}` but it should not be.

Please anyone help me!

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have a placeholder and not provide a value for that, instead you can pass a default empty string for the extra keywod, eg: value = {'username': '@Random', 'servername': 'AnyName', 'extra':''}

Answer (score 1):

Think you are looking for something like this:

```py
msg = '{username} joined {servername} {{extra}}'

value = {'username': '@Random', 'servername': 'AnyName','{extra}': 'X'}
text = msg.format(**value)
print(text)

print(text.format(extra="Anything")) # if you want to print anything for extra
```

- Output:

```
@Random joined AnyName {extra}
@Random joined AnyName Anything
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible but you can use this version:

```
msg = '{username} joined {servername} {extra}'

value = {'username': '@Random', 'servername': 'AnyName'}
msg = msg.format(**{**{'extra': ''}, **value})
print(msg)

# Output
@Random joined AnyName
```

Since Python 3.9, you can merge `dict`

```
msg = '{username} joined {servername} {extra}'

value = {'username': '@Random', 'servername': 'AnyName'}
msg = msg.format(**{'extra': ''} | value)
print(msg)

# Output
@Random joined AnyName
```